# Upload of big file (> 1Go) fails with error "Errno::ENOSPC: No space left on device"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, paperclip, passenger

Rails 3.2.20, Ruby 1.9.3p194, Apache 2.2.22, Passenger 3.0.21.

File are uploaded to `/tmp` (that what I think when looking at the logs:

```
Parameters: {
...
@tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20150317-1329-19lcteh>>
...
}
```

)

Big file uploads (for instance for a 1.8Go file) raise the exception `Errno::ENOSPC: No space left on device - write` with the log trace:

`` /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1372 :in `copy_stream`
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1372 :in `block (2 levels) in copy_file`
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1371 :in `open`
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1371 :in `block in copy_file`
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1370 :in `open`
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1370 :in `copy_file`
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:477 :in `copy_file`
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:396 :in `block in cp`
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1515 :in `block in fu_each_src_dest`
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1531 :in `fu_each_src_dest0`
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1513 :in `fu_each_src_dest`
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:395 :in `cp`
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/paperclip-4.2.0/lib/paperclip/io_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:41 :in `copy_to_tempfile`
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/paperclip-4.2.0/lib/paperclip/io_adapters/uploaded_file_adapter.rb:8 :in `initialize` ``

I don't understand why because the partition where is the `/tmp` directory has plenty of available space:

`Filesystem                                Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                                    9.9G  4.9G  4.6G  52% /`

There is no file size limit in the Apache configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I add a quick look at the paperclip source.  It seems the file content is copied, so it is present 2 time on the disk. (The error trace also shows it)

So to be able to hadle 1.8G file you need at least 3.6G of free space.  If at the same time a 500M file is uploaded (or if there is another copy some where) you don't have anought disk space.

To be able to size the needed storage, you will need to track how your framework is handling uploaded files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you're right, I ended up increase the disk space by a factor of 3 and it fixes the issue.